# ProstgreSQL: Use regexp_split_to_table to Split the Column

Tags: sql, arrays, json, regex, postgresql

I have a column of data in PostgreSQL looks like

```
data
[{'aaa': 3333, 'bbb': 'xxx'}, {'aaa': 44444, 'bbb': 'z'}]
[{'aaa': 11, 'bbb': 'zz'}, {'aaa': 555, 'bbb': 'yyy'}]
```

Basically I want to extract part after

```
'bbb':'
```

and before bracket. Then pivot them from columns to row. So in this case, I want output to look like

```
data1
xxx
z
zz
yyy
```

I am using regexp_split_to_table function but I am not sure how should I write the regular expressions.
I am trying functions below, but it will give me 'aaa', brackets and quotes.

```
regexp_split_to_table(genres, '},')
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strings do look like json arrays (provided that you replace single quotes with double quotes), so I would suggest json functions here.

```
select x.js ->> 'bbb' as genre
from mytable t
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(replace(t.genres, '''', '"')::jsonb) x(js)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=aab66afb3d68f9c9dd4e0287fbf0d0a5)**:

```
| genre |
| :---- |
| xxx   |
| z     |
| zz    |
| yyy   |
```

Comment: Thanks GMB! Unfortunately data is stored in ProstgreSQL, I guess data was pulled by JSON then saved to SQL.

Comment: @BonjugaLewis: that's my point. You can turn these strings to json, then use json functions. See the demo that I added to my answer (where the datatype of the `genre` column is `text`).

Comment: @BonjugaLewis: the real question is: why wasn't this stored as valid JSON?